# Spring Boot: Static content serving CSS correctly but not JS

Tags: spring, spring-boot

We're trying to serve a React app via Spring Boot.

Spring is able to serve the CSS folder's css files (src/main/resources/static/css/*), but is not able to serve the JS folder's files (src/main/resources/static/js/*). There is a main.8f965741.chunk.js inside the JS folder, and when we run the application, it is returning an error 404.

It is not a browser/caching issue.
It is not a folder/file permissions issue.

Any thoughts on how to debug this? Spring gives us essentially no output for the 404.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn on DEBUG (or TRACE) level logs by adding the following to your `application.properties`:

> logging.level.org.springframework.web: TRACE

Then try requesting the JS file directly, perhaps with curl (e.g., `curl http://localhost:8080/js/main.8f965741.chunk.js`)

The logs should tell you how the request was mapped and how it was subsequently handled.  You can compare the logs generated here with a "known good" request (perhaps from requesting a css file).

If you've built a .jar or .war artifact, you can also unpack it (using `jar xf ...`) and double check if the js files are properly packaged there.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! We're pretty new to Spring and this helped us figure it out. We were serving from src/main/resources but the problem went away when we build a .jar so we're going with that for now.